# Exclude from click function when parent LI has class

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to add a click function to an A element UNLESS the parent LI has a certain class (.current)

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$('ul li:not(.current) a').click(function (e) {
```

Here's a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WvPE7/

I don't want the click function to execute for 'ul li.current a' - just 'ul li a' (without .current)

Surely I've missed something very simple... any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a small condition instead of using `:not('.current')`.

```
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) return;
```

The events are bound when you run `$('ul li:not(.current) a')` and at that point, there are no li with class current.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WvPE7/5/

**Full Code:**

```
$('ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) return;

    $('p').hide();
    $('li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('p.' + myClass).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple delegation using the `.on()` method:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function(e) {
    // ...
});
```

You can find out more about `.on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

---

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/WvPE7/7/

Comment: Your answer is not any different than mine I'm afraid. Please, be sure to check other people's answers before posting. Don't forget that you can also contribute to other people's answers

Answer (score -1):

turn

```
$('ul li:not(.current) a').click(function (e) {
```

into

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function (e) {
```

Comment: @RT check my answer or answer from undefined